# Cloud Functions for Firebase: how to get the user triggering the event?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I see Cloud Functions for Firebase including [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate) is triggered by CRUD operations on Firebase Realtime Database.
In my project, I need to record which users have written/updated/deleted  specific fields.
For example:

```
{
   "news": { 
      `news id`: { 
          "createdBy": `user id`, 
          "title""text": "...",
           ...
       },
       ...
   }
}
```

So when a user create a new `News` object.  I need to record who created it.
I can do this by the field  `createdBy` but I need a more secure method to get the `uid` of the user triggered the CRUD operations.

Comment: What do you mean for "more secure"?

Comment: `createdBy` is filled by the user in the frontend. But I need the user's uid who made changes to the db.

Comment: Look into database rules and validations. You can write a rule to ensure that the `createdBy` value is equal to the user thats logged in, therefore cannot be faked.